# Segmentation fault while switching QCompleter for QLineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt4, textchanged, qcompleter

I have data coming from two sources , one from XML file save paths , second one from `QFileSystemModel` which I want to work if the user couldn't see the path then in `QLineEdit` the user should be able to browse path !! the first letter obviously "/" or single letter for windows .

just for the example I have simple replaced the XMLData from file to defaultList of paths.

The below code works for a while but I get segmentation fault.

```
from PyQt4.Qt import Qt, QObject,QLineEdit
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSlot,SIGNAL,SLOT
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

import sys

class DirLineEdit(QLineEdit, QtCore.QObject):
    """docstring for DirLineEdit"""


def __init__(self):
    super(DirLineEdit, self).__init__()
    self.defaultList = ['~/Development/python/searchMethod', '~/Development/Nuke_python',
'~/Development/python/openexr', '~/Development/python/cpp2python',
 '~/Development/python/using_argparse', '~Development/python/listFilter']
    self.textChanged.connect(self.switchCompleter)
    self._pathsList()

def focusInEvent(self, event):
    QtGui.QLineEdit.focusInEvent(self, event)
    self.completer().complete()

def switchCompleter(self):
    if len(self.text()) >= 1:
        self.__dirCompleter()
    if len(self.text()) == 0:
        self.__pathsList()

def __dirCompleter(self):
    dirModel = QtGui.QFileSystemModel() 
    dirModel.setRootPath(QtCore.QDir.currentPath()) 
    dirModel.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.AllDirs | QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QtCore.QDir.Files) 
    dirModel.setNameFilterDisables(0) 
    completer = QtGui.QCompleter(dirModel, self)    
    completer.setModel(dirModel)
    completer.setCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive) 
    self.setCompleter(completer)

def _pathsList(self):
    completerList = QtCore.QStringList()
    for i in self.defaultList:
        completerList.append(QtCore.QString(i))
    lineEditCompleter = QtGui.QCompleter(completerList)
    lineEditCompleter.setCompletionMode(QtGui.QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
    self.setCompleter(lineEditCompleter)



app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
smObj = DirLineEdit()
smObj.show()    
app.exec_()
```

the above code gives Segmentation fault: 11
Is there a better way I can use both completer with one ?

Comment: I have tried few modification and pasted the changes [here](http://pastebin.com/Jxziq8hW)

Now , the thing is I am not able to select the path that comes as completer is switched. e.g.. I can select any of the path after "/" say /Users or/Applications etc..
on trying to attempt this segmentation fault occurs.

Comment: You are calling the wrong parent class __init__ for the model posted in that pastebin link.

Comment: what do you mean ? I hope you didn't meant by `ReadWriteCustomPathsToDisk` !! can u show me with example ?

Comment: `QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__` should be `QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__`

Comment: well, I can even use super, but that is not the issue. You are not pointing in the right direction.

Comment: right, using super I can avoid the issue, however, my question is different.